# Adding Input data validation to accept only integer values greater than 0

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, try-catch, tryparse

Im simulating a vending machine and would like to set the product quantity text box to only accept values greater than 0. when i enter -1 my program accepts this value and displays it which i dont want.can someone help please

code is:

```
//create a new Employee object
    try // Exception handling to ensure that incorrect data type cannot be entered into text box creating a new product
       {
            Products newProd = new Products(this.textProdID.Text);
            newProd.ProductName= this.textProdName.Text;
            newProd.ProductQuantity= Convert.ToInt32(this.textProdQuantity.Text);
            newProd.ProductPrice= Convert.ToDouble(this.textProdPrice.Text);
            ProductList.Add(newProd);
            MessageBox.Show(newProd.ProdName + " has been added to the product list");
        }
     catch
     {
        MessageBox.Show("Format entered into text box Is incorrect please check and try again");
     }
```

Comment: You are probably getting down votes because you aren't really even asking a question clearly

Comment: Your code does not contain specified data range validation (>0); you have to add that line and throw ArgumentException if validation fail. Best regards,

Comment: How are you checking if the value entered is > 0?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the Quantity range validation as per your specification - see the code snippet shown below:

```
//create a new Employee object
    try // Exception handling to ensure that incorrect data type cannot be entered into text box creating a new product
       {
            Products newProd = new Products(this.textProdID.Text);
            newProd.ProductName= this.textProdName.Text;
            newProd.ProductQuantity= Convert.ToInt32(this.textProdQuantity.Text);
            // add the input range validation 
            if (newProd.ProductQuantity<=0) throw new ArgumentException ("Quantity must be a positive number.");

            newProd.ProductPrice= Convert.ToDouble(this.textProdPrice.Text);
            ProductList.Add(newProd);
            MessageBox.Show(newProd.ProdName + " has been added to the product list");
        }
     catch
     {
        MessageBox.Show("Format entered into text box Is incorrect please check and try again");
     }
```

Another solution is just to show a MessageBox with error message if validation fail and return. Further performance optimization can be achieved by using `TryParse()` instead of `Convert` method, but considering relatively simple task, both solutions pertinent to this case will suffice the purpose. As a general recommendation, consider adding the input validation to the Control event (e.g. `TextBox.TextChanged +=(s,e)=>{ // validation};`
Also, pertinent to your case, consider setting the object to null in validation fail.

Hope this will help. Best regards,

Comment: Alex, I like the fact that you are putting in validation but this is a horrible idea... to use Try/Catch and throw errors for validation. 

Try catch should never, IMHO, be used for validation. It should be used for catching Unhandled Exceptions.

Comment: Try/Catch is a mechanism for developers and API designers to communicate and catch exceptional situations in the development pipeline. They are not intended for data validation and they should not be used this way. It is slow and expensive to throw and catch an exception just for data validation purposes.

Comment: Listen, folks, the person asked for the practical solution and a simplest way is to add this line of code. There are many other ways to achieve the goal (the best way probably will be to add the validation to the input control on .Change event), but I don't know the rest of the code. He probably should add "Finally" statement to set obj to null, or add it to 'catch' block, but this is a long story. Best regards,